# Mandar a imprimir un txt a una impresora por USB en python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, usb

mi duda es que quiero mandar a imprimir un archivo txt dentro de un programa de Python, y pues tambien busco la manera de que al apretar cierta tecla o hacer algo con el teclado se mande a imprimir, ya que lo quiero dentro de un while

edit: Tengo ubuntu 18.04 LTS y mi impresora es una EPSON L365

```
while(true)

    if(presiono algo)
    imprimir archivo.txt
```